# What is AirPrint and how is it different from existing network printing protocols?

Tags: network-printer

I am about to buy a new printer and I want to buy network (WiFi) enabled printer. I've seen different models from different vendors -  Some of the printers explicitly marked with AirPrint support. But I could not understand if only those can be used with AirPrint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airprint basically uses the zeroconf/bonjour protocol to set up printing with minimal configuration - Airprint support simply means it has support for zeroconf baked in. If not they'd just have some driver based wireless printing setup.

Answer (score 0):

i thought airprint was for printing from iphone and ipad? as far as i can tell i think only those will be able to comm with ios versions to print to or to auto discover. you might be able to get an app that will allow you to query wifi enabled printers but that is not as easy as using airprint.gd
http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/airprint.html